# What makes an avalanche photo diode single photon sensitive?

Tags: photons

Looking at APDs classed as single photon sensitive, they seem to have greater responsivity and lower dark current. Are these the determining factors for making an APD a good single photon detector?

Comment: Certainly one needs a detector that (a) responds to a single photon by putting out a measurable signal, and (b) generally does not respond if there isn't a photon interacting with it. You need signal, and want more signal than noise. However, any real setup may have other requirements to meet.

Answer (score 0):

It only takes one photon to start an avalanche, and you want no action in the dark.